# how to add the value in column of datagrid view?

Tags: asp.net

I have a data grid view and a text box.I need to add the values of  columns i.e every time the value is inserted in the particular column in every row.All the value of that column is added and the result is shown in the text box.

Comment: I am unable to create the code so help me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please see the code if it helps]

This code takes some parameters and then traverse through gridview to find the control of textbox and add value in sales variable.